# Swagger 5.2.3 SupportedSubmitMethods removed?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I noticed that from version 5.0 and above the SupportedSubmitMethods option has been removed and now all HTTP verbs are implicitly supported, according to [this part of the Swashbuckle documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#transitioning-to-swashbuckle-50).

Is there a way to choose which HTTP verbs will support the "Try it out" option in swagger 5.X.X ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so. You can however modify the behavior of swagger ui. [VisualBean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841212/visualbean) has put a [solution here](http://visualbean.io/blog/remove-try-it-out-buttons-from-swagger-ui/)

The idea of his solution is to let Swashbuckle inject custom javascript that removes buttons with specific classes (eg .put .submit and .post .submit).